# Como fazer um clone de uma lista ligada em c?

Tags: c

Como posso fazer uma lista ligada sem ser recursiva, tenho isto até ao momento.

**Código**:

```
typedef struct slist *LInt;

typedef struct slist {
    int valor;
    LInt prox;
}Nodo;



LInt clone (LInt a) {
    LInt k;
    if(a==NULL) {return NULL;}
    else {
        while(a!=NULL) {
            k=(LInt)malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
            k->valor=a->valor;
            a=a->prox;
            k->prox=a;
        }
        return k;
    }
}
```

Quem poder ajudar, fico agradecido.
Obrigado

Comment: Acredito que o que falta, da sua estrutura, é salvar a "cabeça". Então, no primeiro paço você faz cabeca->valor = a-> valor; cabeca->prox = a->prox; E então faz a iteração com o resto da lista (utilizando o k mesmo como auxiliar) e retornar o cabeca

Comment: O que exatemente você quer dizer por "sem ser recursiva"?

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que eu entendo, não recursiva é em uma função onde não há chamada de si mesma. Logo, seria algo assim:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct
{
    int valor;
    void* proximo; //semelhante a "lista* proximo"
} lista;

lista* lista_construir()
{
    lista* ptr = (lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
    (*ptr).proximo = 0;
    (*ptr).valor = 0;
    return ptr;

}
lista* lista_ampliar(lista* lista_, unsigned int tamanho)
{
    if(tamanho == 0) return lista_;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < tamanho; i++)
        (*(lista_ + i)).proximo = lista_construir();
    return lista_;
}

unsigned int lista_tamanho(lista* lista_)
{
    unsigned int tamanho = 1;
    lista* copia = lista_;
    while(copia->proximo != 0)
    {
        tamanho++;
        copia = copia->proximo;
    }
    return tamanho;
}
lista* lista_clonar(lista* lista_)
{
    lista* ret = lista_construir();
    lista_ampliar(ret, lista_tamanho(lista_) - 1);
    lista* endereco_ret = ret; //endereço primordial

    lista* copia_lista = lista_;
    while(1)
    {
        ret->valor = copia_lista->valor;
        if(copia_lista->proximo == 0)
        return endereco_ret;
        else
        {
            if(ret->proximo == 0)
                exit(-1);
            else
                ret = ret->proximo;
                copia_lista = copia_lista->proximo;
            continue;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    lista* lista_ = lista_construir();
    lista_->valor = 1;
    lista_ampliar(lista_, 1);
    ((lista*)lista_->proximo)->valor = 2;

    lista* clone = lista_clonar(lista_);

    return (lista_->valor != clone->valor) && (((lista*)(lista_->proximo))->valor != ((lista*)(lista_->proximo))->valor); //Deve retornar 0
}
```

O conceito é apenas ir seguindo os ponteiros até chegar onde temos que chegar (ponteiro nulo).
Note que quando lidamos com memória "em gestão" (tentativa em português de falar *managed memory*), devemos checar todos os casos para nada de errado ocorra; logo, todos os ponteiros devem ser testados antes do uso imediato do programador.